# Why CSS Transitions -module does not support image-to-image transitions?

Tags: css, transition

I've read the spec for [CSS Transitions Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/) and I'd like to know why it does not support image-based transitions.

According to the draft, the background-image transitions are only supported when using with gradients. Both Webkit and Gecko seems to follow this practice.

It's just that I see this as a major drawback. HTML 5 and CSS 3 could become the killer of Flash, but if I can't even transit between two images, I don't see how one could have beautiful menus without Flash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree, I would love to see a way to transition between image.  A way to do it is to use two absolutely positioned images and fade from one into the other by animating the opacity on :hover.

As to why it is not in the spec, it may be good to ask the w3c.